# Change shortcuts in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shortcuts

What is the easiest way to change shortcuts in Inkscape?

After watching a few tutorials it seems that the most widespread way to do this is by changing a little bit of code. But is there a less manual way to do this?

Specifically I would like to set the shortcut which would select the node selector. I am using Windows 10 and by default it is set here to be <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is, my fellow Inkscape designer.

Press <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**P**</kbd> -> go to *Interface* -> *Keyboard Shortcuts* -> change shortcuts.

As easy as that.

Comment: well, for me, don't have that option.
I mean, the shortcut fields are not editable (Preferences)